# VBS convert string to floating point

Tags: vbscript

```
Dim strnumber
strnumber = "0.3"

Dim add
add = 0.1

Dim result 
result  = strnumber +  add

MsgBox result
```

I want to get `0.4` as result, but get `3.1`.
I tried `clng(strnumber)` and `int(strnumber)`, nothing works. There is a simple solution for sure but I won't find it.

EDIT: Solution

```
result  = CDbl(Replace(strnumber,".",",") +  add
```

Comment: This should work as is. I tested it on my machine and it did. If nothing else,  try with  `result  = CDbl(strnumber) +  CDbl(add)`

Comment: I still get 3.1 (on a different machine by now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add two numbers. So you should use numbers (and not a string (strnumber) and a number (add):

```
>> n1 = 0.3
>> n2 = 0.1
>> r  = n1 + n2
>> WScript.Echo r
>>
0,4
```

As you can see from the output (0,4), I'm using a locale (German) that uses "," as decimal 'point'. But **literals** always use ".". So by using the proper data types you can write your scripts in a language/locale independent fashion as long as you don't need to process external string data (from a file or user input). Then you have to modify the input **before** you feed it to a conversion function like CDbl(). For simple cases that can be done with Replace(inp, badmarker, goodmarker).

P.S. You said you " tried clng(strnumber) and int(strnumber)". You should have tried CDbl(). CLng() tries to get a long integer (cf. CInt()), Int() removes/rounds the fraction from number.

Comment: I read that "string number" from a text field so there is no real number. Text is text. Once I've tried the `replace` part, but not in combination with CDbl then. Now it works. Such stupid time consuming problems, dooh.

Answer (score 2):

Has to do with your locale settings. Automatic conversion  (as well as explicit one) observes it in the same manner as in `CStr()` function.

E.g. in my locale `CStr( 0.3)` results to `0,3` that is invert to `CDbl("0,3")` while `CDbl("0.3")` results to an error.

BTW: always use `option explicit` and, for debugging purposes, `On Error Goto 0`

Answer (score 2):

Following below procedures can help:

1. Replacing the dot(".") with comma (",") in the string
2. change the string to double by Cdbl

**example:**

```
dim a,b,c

a="10.12"

b="5.05"

a=Replace(a,".",",")

b= Replace(b,".",",")

c=Cdbl(a)+Cdbl(b)

msgbox c
```