# To convert string to double in UFT/QTP

Tags: hp-uft

I am trying to convert string to double in UFT but It shows the output without decimal point. below is the code for reference.

```
vStr = "1000000.589765"
msgbox Typename(vStr)
strV1=CDBL(formatNumber(vStr,4))
msgbox Typename(strV1)
print strV1
```

Output: 1000000589765

Note that without formatNumber, its not working.

Comment: The code is correct ... I got 1000000.5898 in my test. Try to clear the print area and check again ... maybe in your code you are printing vStr and not strV1. You don't need formatnumber to be honest

Comment: I had executed the same code and the output is without decimal. Not sure why that is happening. Also when I remove "formatNumber" this does not works and the value is not converting to double.

Comment: I wonder if this is more of a VB problem rather than specific to HP-UFT. Ive flagged it as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBS convert string to floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037795/vbs-convert-string-to-floating-point)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another implementation using DotNetFactory. Just an another thought. I am not denying to use **CDbl**. But worth to give a shot.

```
'Test Code
Dim strConvertedCode
strConvertedCode = ConvertDataType("1000000.589765","Double")
If strConvertedCode <> null Then
    Msgbox strConvertedCode 
End If

Public Function ConvertDataType(ByVal SourceData,ByVal ConversionDataType)
    'Initialization of variables 
    Dim objDotNetFactory
    Dim strConvertedData : strConvertedData = null
    Dim strSystemNamespace
    'Determine the destination data type
    Select Case UCase(ConversionDataType)
        Case "DOUBLE"   
            strSystemNamespace = "System.Double"
        'Implement further for your data types
        'Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360(v=vs.90).aspx
        Case Default
            Set objDotNetFactory = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Int32")
    End Select
    Set objDotNetFactory = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance(strSystemNamespace)
    'Check the dot net factory instance is successful
    If Not IsObject(objDotNetFactory) Then
        Reporter.ReportEvent micWarning,"Data type convertor","Conversion from String to " & ConversionDataType & " failed, Since DotNetFactory instance was not created."
        ConvertDataType = strConvertedData
        Exit Function
    End If
    strConvertedData = objDotNetFactory.Parse(SourceData)
    ConvertDataType = strConvertedData
End Function
```