# how to convert String to Double Microsoft VBScript

Tags: string, vbscript, double

i want to convert the String "0.265" to number 0.265 in Microsoft VBScript 
  any function  to do that ?

Comment: I'm not sure why as it will be a double if it needs to be. `CDbl` is the conversion. Help file is at http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe.

Comment: CDbl error "type not compatible"

Comment: `A="0.265"` `B=CDbl(A)` `Msgbox B`.

Comment: Check your locale settings as VBScript works off your system regional settings, might not use `.`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBS convert string to floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037795/vbs-convert-string-to-floating-point)